# Handling Parent Property Event

Tags: vb.net, oop

Is it possible to listen to a parent class' object's event via the property accessor?

What I've tried (a minimal example):

```
Public Class ParentFoo
  Private WithEvents m_bar As EventyObj
  Public Property Bar() As EventyObj
    Get
      Return m_bar
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As EventyObj)
      m_bar = value
    End Set
  End Property
End Class
```

---

```
Public Class ChildFoo
  Inherits ParentFoo

  [...]

  Public Sub Bar_OnShout() Handles Bar.Shout
    ' Some logic
  End Sub
End Class
```

The specific error message I'm getting (VS2005) is "Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types." Does accessing a private WithEvents variable via a public property strip away the 'WithEvents'?

Comment: I don't understand what your trying to achieve here. The child class derives from the parent so it has access it any member you gave to the parent - directly! Because it 'is a' parent class. Try explaining what your goal is.

Comment: @DonA: That isn't accurate. ChildFoo cannot access m_bar directly, as it is declared 'Private' in the parent class. I could get around this issue by declaring it protected, but I'd rather not do that unless I absolutely must.

What I'm trying to achieve is listening to a private, parent class' object's events via an accessor property, through the existing WithEvents/Handles shorthand.

Comment: I get that, my point is you can access members - isn't that what you want? I don't think events are going to work for you like that.

Comment: I think we're talking past one another. I can't access a private member directly; I can access it via a property, but for some reason, the WithEvents is getting stripped. I'm curious why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ParentFoo:

```
Public Overridable Sub OnShout() Handles m_bar.Shout
'No Logic Necessary
End Sub
```

In ChildFoo:

```
Public Overrides OnShout()
'Logic Here
End Sub
```

Since ParentFoo will call OnShout when m_bar raises a Shout Event and you override it in ChildFoo, your ChildFoo's OnShout will handle that event.